# Definir TimeZone padrão Golang

Tags: time, golang

Existe alguma forma de definir um TimeZone (Location) padrão no Golang para não precisar ficar setando hora?

Atualmente estou setando manualmente o TimeZone toda vez que eu preciso trabalhar com Time usando isso:

```golang
loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("America/Sao_Paulo")
tim := time.Now().In(loc)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode setar a váriavél [`time.Local`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Location). Segundo a documentação:

> **var Local** ***Location = &localLoc**

> Local represents the system's local time zone. On Unix systems, Local > consults the TZ environment variable to find the time zone to use. No > TZ means use the system default /etc/localtime. TZ="" means use UTC. > TZ="foo" means use file foo in the system timezone directory.

Então você pode usar para mudar o Local.

---

Por exemplo:

```
time.Local = time.UTC
```

Dessa forma ao executar o `time.Now()` será em UTC.

---

No caso do `America/Sao_Paulo` bastaria fazer:

```
time.Local, _ = time.LoadLocation("America/Sao_Paulo")
```

Isso pode ser declarado no `main()` e todas as chamadas subsequentes utilizarão esse fuso-horário.

---

Se fizer um teste:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println("Tempo padrão:", time.Now())

    time.Local = time.UTC
    fmt.Println("Tempo UTC:", time.Now())
    fmt.Println("Tempo UTC:", time.Now())

    time.Local, _ = time.LoadLocation("America/Sao_Paulo")
    fmt.Println("Tempo SP:", time.Now())
    fmt.Println("Tempo SP:", time.Now())
}
```

Resultado:

```
Tempo padrão: 2021-06-17 15:28:04.5675042 +0100 BST m=+0.092369601
Tempo UTC: 2021-06-17 14:28:04.5844768 +0000 UTC m=+0.109342201
Tempo UTC: 2021-06-17 14:28:04.5844768 +0000 UTC m=+0.109342201
Tempo SP: 2021-06-17 11:28:04.5844768 -0300 -03 m=+0.109342201
Tempo SP: 2021-06-17 11:28:04.5844768 -0300 -03 m=+0.109342201
```

Comment: Show de bola! Funcionou perfeitamente! Sabe me dizer se sempre existiu essa varíavel? Porque anos atras quando eu pesquisei não achei nada.

Comment: Sempre existiu, ao menos desde do Go 1.0.1, lá de ~2012. Pode ver o código fonte em https://go.googlesource.com/go/+/refs/tags/go1.0.1/src/pkg/time/zoneinfo.go#57.

Comment: Entendi. Estranho que quando eu pesquisei não achei isso em lugar nenhum, e eu pesquisei muito, muito mesmo, ai como não achei nada na época acabei criando uma função que inicializa um novo time.time no timezone que eu quero. Mas esse jeito ai é mais simples e é nativo do GO. Muito obrigado novamente.

Comment: Essa solução é perfeita porque é multiplataforma! A solução usando a variavel de sistema TZ, igual citada nas respostas abaixo só funciona em ambiente linux.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode criar um package em separado setando esta configuração e importá-lo nos locais em que precisar, por exemplo:

```
package tzinit

import (
    "os"
)

func init() {
    os.Setenv("TZ", "America/Sao_Paulo")
}
```

Importando configuração

package main

```
import _ "path_pacote/tzinit"

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    //mais algum outro pacote
)
```

Espero ter ajudado !

Comment: Já tinha visto esta resposta em outros tópicos e ela simplesmente não funciona. Já havia feito alguns testes com ela e não funciona.
Caso quiser testar você pode usar o seguinte trecho de código: https://play.golang.org/p/-RnSNe2HVY2

Comment: Depois de alguns anos eu descobri que essa solução de setar a variavel de ambiente TZ só funciona em ambientes linux/unix, em ambiente Windows não. Nesse caso é só usar time.Local = time.UTC

Answer (score -1):

É necessário utilizar a função [time.Now().In()](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.In)

```
loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("America/Sao_Paulo")
// handle err
currentTime := time.Now().In(loc)

// outra forma de fazer o exemplo acima
loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("America/Sao_Paulo")
currentTime := time.Now()
currentTime.In(loc)
```

[Exemplo no Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/i19Wx52KRD9)

Comment: Isso não define um timezone padrão para todas as datas que é oque eu quero. Isso vai definir um padrão para a minha variavel atual do time.

Answer (score -1):

Seta direto na máquina, então o time.Now() vem com a timezone certo.

Exemplo de Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata
ENV TZ=America/Sao_Paulo
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
```

Comment: É uma boa alternativa, daria pra ver pra setar esses ENV pelo GO, porque nem todo mundo usa Docker, mas é uma ótima ideia setar ENV. Alias, você testou ver se isso funciona?

Comment: Setando essa timezone na máquina do servidor tem o mesmo resultado, caso não use docker.